# How to Lookup and Reference Keywords when Parsing in R

Tags: r, substring, gsub

I have a character vector in my data frame in R. I would like to look up keywords in each element, reference said keyword, and call, to a new vector, which ever word is x-number of words away from the keyword I just looked up.

For example, say I have the following data frame:

```
> v1 <- c(1:5)
> v2 <- c("abc def ghi", "jkl mno def", "pqr stu vwx", "abc def yz", "ghi jkl mno def")
> sample <- as.data.frame(cbind(v1, v2))
> sample$v1 <- as.numeric(sample$v1)
> sample$v2 <- as.character(sample$v2)
> sample
  v1              v2
1  1     abc def ghi
2  2     jkl mno def
3  3     pqr stu vwx
4  4      abc def yz
5  5 ghi jkl mno def
> str(sample)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ v1: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ v2: chr  "abc def ghi" "jkl mno def" "pqr stu vwx" "abc def yz" ...
```

And, I'd like to create vector `v3` that looks up the word "def" in each element and returns the word immediately prior. So, for example, `v3` should look like:

```
> v3
[1] "abc" "mno" NA    "abc" "mno"
```

How do I write a function to do this automatically?

I have a function I've been using to lookup keywords and replace them with the same thing every time. Altered for this example, it looks something like this:

```
> f1 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'def'){
+   df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
+     ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), TRUE, 
+            i))
+   return(df)
+ }
> sample$v3 = NA
> sample = f1(sample, cols = c('v3'), match_with = sample$v2)
> sample
  v1              v2   v3
1  1     abc def ghi TRUE
2  2     jkl mno def TRUE
3  3     pqr stu vwx   NA
4  4      abc def yz TRUE
5  5 ghi jkl mno def TRUE
> str(sample)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v1: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ v2: chr  "abc def ghi" "jkl mno def" "pqr stu vwx" "abc def yz" ...
 $ v3: logi  TRUE TRUE NA TRUE TRUE
```

I've done some research on this site and others one what to replace "TRUE" with, in `f1`, so that, instead of returning "TRUE," it returns the word immediately prior to the keyword I want to lookup as a reference. I think I'm close. Here's what I have so far:

```
> ptn <- "(.*? )"
> f2 <- function(df, cols, match_with, to_x = 'def'){
+   df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(i) 
+     ifelse(grepl(to_x, match_with, fixed = TRUE), gsub(ptn, " ", sample$v2), 
+            i))
+   return(df)
+ }
> sample$v3 = NA
> sample = f2(sample, cols = c('v3'), match_with = sample$v2)
> sample
  v1              v2     v3
1  1     abc def ghi    ghi
2  2     jkl mno def    def
3  3     pqr stu vwx   <NA>
4  4      abc def yz     yz
5  5 ghi jkl mno def    def
> str(sample)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ v1: num  1 2 3 4 5
 $ v2: chr  "abc def ghi" "jkl mno def" "pqr stu vwx" "abc def yz" ...
 $ v3: chr  "  ghi" "  def" NA "  yz" ...
```

This looks up my keyword and returns the last word of the element. But the question persists, how do I reference the keyword I'm looking up and return a word some relative distance away from it? Specifically, what pattern must I replace `"(.*? )"` with to return the word immediately prior to "def"?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution. Let me know if this is what you were looking for:

```
library(dplyr)
sample %>% mutate(v3=gsub("(\\w+\\s)*(\\w+)\\sdef.*","\\2",v2),v3=ifelse(v2==v3,NA,v3))
# v1              v2   v3
# 1  1     abc def ghi  abc
# 2  2     jkl mno def  mno
# 3  3     pqr stu vwx <NA>
#   4  4      abc def yz  abc
# 5  5 ghi jkl mno def  mno
```

with base R

```
sample$v3 <- gsub("(\\w+\\s)*(\\w+)\\sdef.*","\\2",sample$v2)
sample$v3[sample$v3==sample$v2] <- NA
# v1              v2   v3
# 1  1     abc def ghi  abc
# 2  2     jkl mno def  mno
# 3  3     pqr stu vwx <NA>
#   4  4      abc def yz  abc
# 5  5 ghi jkl mno def  mno
```

To get the one after..

```
sample %>% mutate(v3=gsub("(\\w+\\s)*def\\s(\\w+)(\\s\\w+)*","\\2",v2),v3=ifelse(v2==v3,NA,v3))
```